# Нарисовать линии на JS (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

появилась нужда сделать данную вещь, подскажите, с чего начать и как лучше сделать подобное?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что подобное? Распишите более подробно, что надо. Покажите, что уже сделали.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko если бы я знал как это сделать на JS я бы не спрашивал. У меня готова Верстка данных элементов. Мне нужно сделать линии на css и в будущем динамическими

Comment: Понятнее от вашего комментария не стало. Покажите, что у вас готово. И опишите **подробнее**, что вы хотите и что **именно** не получается.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Мне нужно провести линии от точки I к каждой icon по определенным координатам используя JavaScript или jQuery, и при перестроении эти линии должны автоматически оставаться на той же координате относительно icon

Comment: Покажите, что уже сделали.